# Were monastic training texts written down during the Buddha's life?

Tags: pali-canon, sutras, texts, vinaya, buddhadharma

It seems a commonly held notion that the actual written text of Buddhadharma were only recorded well after the life of the Buddha. However, this sutta seems to indicate that was not so:

> "Take a mendicant who says: ‘Reverend, I have heard and learned this
> in the presence of the Buddha: this is the teaching, this is the
> training, this is the Teacher’s instruction.’ You should neither
> approve nor dismiss that mendicant’s statement. Instead, you should
> carefully memorize those words and phrases, then check if they’re
> included in the discourses and **found in the texts on monastic
> training.** If they’re not included in the discourses and found in the
> texts on monastic training, you should draw the conclusion: ‘Clearly
> this is not the word of the Blessed One, the perfected one, the fully
> awakened Buddha. It has been incorrectly memorized by that mendicant.’
> And so you should reject it."
>
> [AN 4.180](https://suttacentral.net/an4.180/en/sujato)

Isn't this prima facie evidence that contrary to this belief that actual teachings were written down and consulted during the life of the Buddha?

Comment: it might be evidence AN 4.180 is fake and written after the buddha. the only True Dhamma is what can be verified as true & real in the here & now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that "text"  there is an artefact of the translation-into-English -- it says "texts" and you think "written".

A simpler and more common translation is just, "found in the suttas and the vinaya".

You can use the "views" icon on the page menu to enable side-by-side display of the Pali.

> Instead, you should carefully memorize those words and phrases, then check if they’re included in the discourses and found in the texts on monastic training.
> Anabhinanditvā appaṭikkositvā tāni padabyañjanāni sādhukaṁ uggahetvā sutte otāretabbāni, vinaye sandassetabbāni.

I'm not sure any of the Pali words say "written text".

I haven't found a clear translation of *sandassetabbāni*, here's a footnote from *Buddhism: Buddhist origins and the early history of Buddhism in South and Southeast Asia*
edited by Paul Williams (in a chapter titled, "On the very idea of the Pali canon"):

[image]

... which at least implies it's understood to mean something like, "compared with", not, "written text".

Answer (score 0):

This is an inaccuracy in the translation of Ven. Sujato.

Let's compare it against the translation of Ven. Anandajoti on [this page](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Texts-and-Translations/Mahaparinibbanasuttam/28-References.htm):

> *Sutte osāretabbāni Vinaye sandassetabbāni.*
> they should be laid
> alongside the Discourses, they should be compared with the Discipline.

Here the latter translates "Vinaya" as "Discipline". The former translates it as "texts on monastic training".